# Composer returning question marks

Tags: laravel, composer-php

My mac is installed with composer and it works fine. I then clone a laravel project. When I run composer update, some of the dependencies require some php stuff to be downloaded first, like php53-mcrypt. After installing the php stuff, i ran composer update again, it returns a bunch of question marks. A bit of googling returns me answers that require to set the

```
detect_unicode=Off
```

in the php.ini. Set it off but still the same. Reinstall composer with the following command

```
curl -s getcomposer.org/installer | php -d detect_unicode=Off
```

Still the same. Anyone can help?

Comment: Post the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, I had to make sure I added the detect_unicode = off in the correct php.ini file. Reinstall composer with homebrew again and it works.